# Can I say Holt-Winters Method is an example of interpolation?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing, interpolation

I believe it fits under the definition from wiki:

> In the mathematical field of numerical analysis, interpolation is a method of constructing new data points within the range of a discrete set of known data points.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

No. An interpolation is a function that pass exactly through the observed data points. For example, a polynomial with sufficient degree (the number of points less one), or a Fourier trigonometric expansion (if the function is assumed periodic).

The forecasting methods are **approximations**. They do not pass exactly by the observed points, but near by. Which allows for the function to be smoother.

Furthermore, the Holt-Winter method is discrete. It does not give a approximate value for time in between observed data points, but gives point for the next time values. So the word would be **extrapolation** (extra=out-of) rather than **intrapolation** (intra=inside). But, it is not an extrapolation because it an approximation rather than exact values.